# Pesquisar elementos de listas aninhadas

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou com um problema em um código.
Tenho que encontrar um elemento específico(eu sei qual elemento é, mas não sei sua posição, porque ela é aleatória). Em condições normais, eu usaria um `index` e conseguiria facilmente a posição. O problema, é que trata-se de uma matriz onde cada linha é uma lista aninhada, e o método `index` não faz a pesquisa dentro das linhas. O que eu posso fazer para conseguir a posição do elemento que eu quero, nesse caso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você tem um número fixo de aninhamentos (ex.: listas de listas de elementos) - e não arbitrário (listas de listas de listas de listas...) - você pode usar uma compreensão de lista para "aplainá-la" (*flatten*), e então fazer essa busca na lista resultante:

```
>>> x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> [e for l in x for e in l].index(5)
4
>>> (4//3, 4%3)
(1, 1)
```

Entretanto, a informação do índice só é útil se as listas tiverem o mesmo tamanho... Caso contrário (e dada a mania irritante do Python de usar exceções como fluxo de controle) o melhor é fazer uma função mesmo:

```
>>> def indice(elemento, lista):
...     for i,l in enumerate(lista):
...         try:
...             return (i, l.index(elemento))
...         except:
...             pass
...     raise ValueError('O elemento nao esta na lista')
...
>>> indice(5, x)
(1, 1)
```